# egrep search for whitespace

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I'm trying to use egrep with a regex pattern to match whitespace.

I've used RegEx with Perl and C# before and they both support the pattern `\s` to search for whitespace. egrep (or at least the version I'm using) does not seem to support this pattern.

In a few articles online I've come across a shorthand [[:space:]], but this does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Using: SunOS 5.10

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I see the same issue on SunOS 5.10.  `/usr/bin/egrep` does not support extended regular expressions.

Try using `/usr/xpg4/bin/egrep`:

```
$ echo 'this line has whitespace
thislinedoesnthave' | /usr/xpg4/bin/egrep '[[:space:]]'
this line has whitespace
```

Another option might be to just use perl:

```
$ echo 'this line has whitespace
thislinedoesnthave' | perl -ne 'chomp;print "$_\n" if /[[:space:]]/'
this line has whitespace
```

Comment: I don't understand why you say you have the same issue, look like it works with egrep .. ?

Comment: The default egrep does not support advanced character sets like [[:space:]].  You need to either change your PATH or call out the absolute path as I did above.

Comment: Which version of egrep was it?

Answer (score 14):

If you're using 'degraded' versions of grep (I quote the term because most UNIX'es I work on still use the original REs, not those fancy ones with "`\s`" or "`[[:space:]]`" :-), you can just revert to the lowest form of RE.

For example, if `:space:` is defined as spaces and tabs, just use:

```
egrep '[ ^I]' file
```

That `^I` is an actual tab character, not the two characters `^` and `I`.

This is assuming `:space:` **is** defined as tabs and spaces, otherwise adjust the choices within the `[]` characters.

The advantage of using degraded REs is that they should work on all platforms (at least for ASCII; Unicode or non-English languages may have different rules but I rarely find a need).

Comment: A nice solution. I like the idea of working to the lowest common denominator

Comment: [GNU grep 2.5.4 on CMD](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) is happy with `[ \t]+` to match one or more whitespace chars.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bash, then syntax to put a tab in a line is

```
$'foo\tbar'
```

I was recently working with sed to do some fixups on a tab-delimited file. Part of the file was:

```
sed -E -e $'s/\t--QUOTE--/\t"/g'
```

That argument is parsed by bash, and sed sees a regex with literal tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should protect the pattern with quotes (if bash, or anything equivalent for the shell you are using).

[ and ] may have special meaning for the shell.

Answer (score -3):

```
$ cat > file
this line has whitespace
thislinedoesnthave
$ egrep [[:space:]] file 
this line has whitespace
```

Works under debian.

For Solaris, isn't there an "eselect" like (see gentoo) or alternatives file to set default your egrep version?

Have you tried grep -E, because if the egrep that is on your path is not the good one, maybe grep is.

Comment: You might get some credit if you explained where 'here' was. It presumably wasn't Solaris 10.  Or, if it was Solaris 10, then it probably wasn't /usr/bin/egrep that you used.